# Gawk / If / Printf / Print everything in columns

Tags: awk, gawk

Could somebody tell me how I solve this problem :

```
plym    fury    1970    73  2500
chevy   malibu  1999    60  3000
ford    mustang 1965    45  10000
volvo   s80     1998    102 9850
ford    thundbd 2003    15  10500
chevy   malibu  2000    50  3500
bmw     325i    1985    115 450
honda   accord  2001    30  6000
ford    taurus  2004    10  17000
toyota  rav4    2002    180 750
chevy   impala  1985    85  1550
ford    explor  2003    25  9500
```

Command :

```
gawk '{if ($1=="plym")($1="plymouth")};{print}' cars
```

Result :

```
plymouth fury 1970 73 2500
chevy   malibu  1999    60  3000
ford    mustang 1965    45  10000
volvo   s80     1998    102 9850
ford    thundbd 2003    15  10500
chevy   malibu  2000    50  3500
bmw     325i    1985    115 450
honda   accord  2001    30  6000
ford    taurus  2004    10  17000
toyota  rav4    2002    180 750
chevy   impala  1985    85  1550
ford    explor  2003    25  9500
```

I want the line of plymouth to be on the same column like the rest of the details

Answer (score 1):

When parsing the line, Awk ignores all separators (as set in variable `FS`).

If you change any field, Awk recreates the line into `$0` (implicit in your call to `print()` without arguments) by splicing the fields (columns) with `OFS` instead, which is just a single space character by default.

You might try to set `OFS` to a tab character like so:

```
BEGIN { OFS = "\t" }
```

If you are lucky and no identifiers are longer than 7 characters (which seems to be true in the original file), it could work.

But if you require special column width, e.g. because "plymouth" is longer now, you will need to use `printf()` instead, e.g.:

```
{ printf("%-10s %-7s %-7s %-3s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5) }
```

For more information, see your `man awk` or [some web variant of it](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/awk/).

Comment: plymouth is 8 characters

Comment: Yeah, I meant in the original file. It seems it originally uses tabs which makes things easier. In the new file, you might need to use the `printf()` way to keep it in columns.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve tab format of line use `sub` in `awk`

```
awk '{sub(/plym/,"&outh")}1' file | column -t
plymouth  fury     1970  73   2500
chevy     malibu   1999  60   3000
ford      mustang  1965  45   10000
volvo     s80      1998  102  9850
ford      thundbd  2003  15   10500
chevy     malibu   2000  50   3500
bmw       325i     1985  115  450
honda     accord   2001  30   6000
ford      taurus   2004  10   17000
toyota    rav4     2002  180  750
chevy     impala   1985  85   1550
ford      explor   2003  25   9500
```

Comment: This tabs too much. fury is now in the colum of 1999

Comment: @user3657270 It does not tabs to much, it uses one single default tab.  To fix this you need to use the `column -t` to align it correctly.

Comment: @user3657270 Yes.`awk '{if ($1=="plym") sub(/plym/,"&outh")};{print}'` This can be shorten to: `awk '$1=="plym" {sub(/plym/,"&outh")}1` Only difference compare to my solution is that this will not change `plymando` to `plymandoouth`, mine will.